# Создать кнопки меню TelegramBot горизонтально одна за другой

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Я пытаюсь создать меню, чтобы после ввода команды `/start` бот отправлял в чат меню в виде кнопок расположенных горизонтально и одна под другой. У меня пока получается не совсем то, что я хочу сделать
Вот мой код:

```
private void sendMenu(long chatId){
        logger.info("Method sendMessage has been run: {}, {}", chatId, TelegramBotUpdatesListener.GREETINGS_MESSAGE);

        /*InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();

        inlineKeyboardMarkup.addRow(new InlineKeyboardButton("Узнать информацию о приюте"));
        inlineKeyboardMarkup.addRow(new InlineKeyboardButton("Как взять собаку из приюта"));
        inlineKeyboardMarkup.addRow(new InlineKeyboardButton("Прислать отчет о питомце"));
        inlineKeyboardMarkup.addRow(new InlineKeyboardButton("Позвать волонтера"));*/

        ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
                new KeyboardButton("Узнать информацию о приюте"),
                new KeyboardButton("Как взять собаку из приюта"),
                new KeyboardButton("Прислать отчет о питомце"),
                new KeyboardButton("Позвать волонтера"));
        replyKeyboardMarkup.resizeKeyboard(true);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.oneTimeKeyboard(false);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.selective(false);

        SendMessage request = new SendMessage(chatId, TelegramBotUpdatesListener.GREETINGS_MESSAGE)
                .replyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup)
                .parseMode(ParseMode.HTML)
                .disableWebPagePreview(true);

        SendResponse sendResponse = telegramBot.execute(request);
        if (!sendResponse.isOk()){
            int codeError = sendResponse.errorCode();
            String description = sendResponse.description();
            logger.info("code of error: {}", codeError);
            logger.info("description -: {}", description);
        }
    }
```

А вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы эти кнопки были над строкой ввода и шли горизонтально одна под другой ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Код:

`answer` это `class SendMessage`

```
            // Создаем клавиуатуру
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
            answer.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(false);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setOneTimeKeyboard(false);

            // Создаем список строк клавиатуры
            List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<KeyboardRow>();

            // Первая строчка клавиатуры
            KeyboardRow keyboardFirstRow = new KeyboardRow();
            // Добавляем кнопки в первую строчку клавиатуры
            keyboardFirstRow.add("Текст 1");
            keyboardFirstRow.add("Текст 2");

            KeyboardRow keyboard2Row = new KeyboardRow();
            // Добавляем кнопки во вторую строчку клавиатуры
            keyboard2Row.add("Текст 3");
            keyboard2Row.add("Текст 4");
            keyboard2Row.add("Текст 5");

            // Добавляем все строчки клавиатуры в список
            keyboard.add(keyboardFirstRow);
            keyboard.add(keyboard2Row);
            // добавляем список клавиатуре
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
```

#### Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Agzam, спасибо за ответ, но он мне не подходит. Я использую библиотеку pengrad API 6.0 и я , в принципе, вчера вечером докопался, как это сделать